# Small random values in range [0,1], non-uniform, on log scale for GA? in Python

Tags: python, random

I recreated the initialisation and mutation of a Genetic Algorithm and found that if I have a min and max of 0.001 and 1 for the parameters of a chromosome, and do random.uniform(min, max), the probability that a random value lies between [0.1, 1] is ~0.9, and between [0.01, 0.1] is ~0.09, and between [0.001, 0.01] is ~0.009 and so on.. Am I correct on this one?

The same happens for random.randint(1, 1000)/1000.0. This is because both are uniformly distributed right?

This makes sense, but in my opinion it is not fair that a new initialised value is more likely to have a greater value, in case of the GA. The probability should be equal between [0.1, 1.0] and [0.01, 0.1].

I found random number generators with different distribution functions. But it looks that none of them do what I think it should do. (numpy.random.lognormal, random.lognormvariate). Maybe some of them will fit, but I have no idea how to set the mu and sigma to scale between my min and max. Can someone help?

Some code that plots the distribution as a histogram:

```
import random
import numpy as np
min = 0.001
max = 1.0
s = []
for i in range(100000):
    s.append(random.uniform(min, max))

#for i in range(100000):
#    s.append(random.lognormvariate(0.00, 0.5))

print(s)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 500, normed=True)
plt.plot(bins, np.ones_like(bins), linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Edit:
Then this would be the solution, it looks good.

```
import random
import numpy as np
min = 0.001
max = 1.0
s = []
#for i in range(100000):
#    s.append(random.uniform(min, max))
for i in range(100000):
    s.append(10 ** random.uniform(np.log10(min), np.log10(max)))
#for i in range(100000):
#    s.append(random.lognormvariate(0.00, 0.5))
np.log
print(s)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 500, normed=True)
plt.plot(bins, np.ones_like(bins), linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "GA" mean?  Is it a "genetic algorithm"?  We can't really advise you on a random distribution without more information about your use case.  For what it's worth, "I don't think it's fair" doesn't sound like the most scientific reason to choose a random distribution I've heard so far.

Comment: *"in my opinion it is not fair"* - it is precisely fair, and your opinion has nothing to do with it! If you want the outputs to follow a log scale, why not do e.g. `10 ** random.random()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: More like `10 ** random.uniform(-3, 0)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach indeed!